# XT-IDE Universal BIOS does not find master drive on XT CF Lite card

Tags: bios, xt-ide

I have built a [XT CF Lite v4.1](http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergeys-projects/xt-cf-lite) to boot my 286 with a compact flash card. I have configured it via DIP switches to address 300h and I am using the XT-IDE Universal BIOS 2.0.0 beta 3. This is I think the latest version. However the google code site looks rather dead.

I have run xtidecfg and configured the EEPROM accordingly: XT CF Lite card with base 300h, BIOS at CE00h, 2864 style EEPROM. I can write it succesfully.

However, the CF card won't be detected upon bootup.
When I put the CF in an IDE to CF adapter on my Multi I/O card running at 170h, XT IDE Universal BIOS succesfully boots.

I guess I might have made a mistake in soldering the CF socket? I have probed the solder pads and CF pins with a meter and they so far do look fine. But I might have to double check. Are there any other reasons why this might fail?

Comment: Oh, I think I have found the error: I am using the AT BIOS. For some reason that does not seem to recognize the CF card. When I switch to the XT BIOS, everything is fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason the AT BIOS BIN file does not detect the CF cards. You have to use the XT BIN file.

Comment: That is strange. I am trying to get a CF-Lite 4.1 to work on an NCR 386SX. I have not even gotten the XT-IDE BIOS to boot using the AT .bin file. So I should try XT .bin?

Comment: Definitely. For specific problems feel free to post a seperate question.

Comment: By the way, mine works, but the CF socket doesn't work reliably. My SMD skills are sub par. So I use it in conjunction with a 16 bit Multi IO card and a CF adapter until i can get the soldering of the CF socket fixed.